# Menus not changing when button is pressed TFT 128 x 128

Tags: arduino-nano, button, resistor, tft

I've just followed a tutorial so that when a button is pressed it goes through a menu. Click once, next slide. Only issue is it isn't appearing on my screen at all. It has uploaded but I'm a total novice when it comes to breadboards etc. Here is my code:

```
    #include "Ucglib.h" // library for this display
#include <TFT.h> // Hardware-specific library
#include <SPI.h>

#define CS   10
#define DC   8
#define RESET  9 

#define up 5
#define down 6

TFT TFTscreen = TFT(CS, DC, RESET);
const int menuSize = 4;
String menuItems(menuSize);

bool upLastState = HIGH;
bool downLastState = HIGH;

int currentMenu = 0;
String temp;
char currentPrintOut(10);


void setup() 
{
  Serial.begin(9600);

  pinMode(up, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(down, INPUT_PULLUP);

  menuItems[0] = ":)";
  menuItems[1] = ":(";
  menuItems[2] = "X(";
  menuItems[3] = ":S";
  menuItems[4] = ":T";

  //initialize the library
  TFTscreen.begin();

  MenuChanged();
}

void loop() {
  if (digitalRead(up) != upLastState) {
    upLastState = !upLastState;
  }

  if (!upLastState) {
    if (currentMenu > 0) {
      currentMenu--;
    } else {
      currentMenu = menuSize - 1;
    }
    MenuChanged();
  } else {
  }


 if (digitalRead(down) !=downLastState) {
  downLastState = !downLastState;

  if (!downLastState) {
    if (currentMenu < menuSize - 1) {
      currentMenu++;
    } else {
      currentMenu = 0;
    }
    //Serial.printIn(menuItems[currentMenu]);
    MenuChanged();
  } else {
    //Release
  }
 }

   delay(50);
 }

 void MenuChanged() {
  Serial.println(menuItems[currentMenu]);

// clear the screen with a black background
  TFTscreen.background(0,0,0);
  TFTscreen.setTextSize(9);
  TFTscreen.stroke(255,255,255);

  temp = String(menuItems[currentMenu]);
  temp.toCharArray(currentPrintOut, 10);

  TFTscreen.text(currentPrintOut, 40, 32);
}
```

Edited back to original as per request

Comment: remove `#define up 5` and `#define down 6`, we already defined pin 5 for the button. also remove `TFTscreen.text(":)", 40, 32);` which is in front of `defualt:`. the `serial.begin()` and `serial.println()` and `delay(100)` are just for testing the code, you can remove them as well.

Comment: Hi! I've done all that now. It's still racing through every single face so I'm going to try the de bounce and see if it's that. I can't even press a button, it just does it itself haha.  Sorry I wasn't sure if I needed to write anything for default! After this I only have one major thing left to do in my code (that you'll probably wind up helping me again im so sorry I'm so new at this). I'll try my best to fix the face speed through

Comment: Please revert back your original code so others can see what was the problem, you basically cleared the question...

Comment: sure thing, I also had another problem now though haha. I tried to debounce but the faces are even faster now. It's going inbetween faces and won't actually stop on one and still wont let me click the button to activate it :/

Comment: updated the answer with de-bounce, if your questions in this site got an answer which solved your problem please pick them as correct answer by clicking on the "tick" next to the answer. is your push-button normally open or is it normally close?

Comment: Sorry to bother you so much. I guess it wasn't the debounce (I wasnt wrong for once! I did it right go me), it's still going through all the cases just slower. Is there a way to stop on that face if the button is actually pressed? I'm trying to work it out on my own but it just keeps repeating going through the faces and not actually pausing on the one I want when the button is pressed :/

Comment: i suspect it's because you have a normally close push-button, which means push-button is connected until you press it. [link](http://www.learningaboutelectronics.com/images/Normally_Open_Push_Button_Diagrams.png). is it a normally close push button?

Comment: Ah I see that makes sense. I guess I can try to make the space wider with resistors etc? Even thought that's still the electrical current but can't hurt to try

Comment: change the push button with a normally open push button **OR** change this line: `if (buttonStatus == LOW) {}` to `if (buttonStatus == HIGH) {}`

Comment: Hey newbie, I put the button in the middle of the board (like originally) and put both the wires on each end. It somewhat works! I need to double tap the button because sometimes it decides to do it again but I'll try your way too. I'll leave you be for now <3. Thank you so much for your help. I appreciate it more than you know. Here is [my victory photo](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/446294089621569536/630452856356601867/20191007_031425.jpg).

Comment: you're welcome.

Comment: Edit: I managed to fix my problem by putting the wires diagonally (ground left pin, 5 right side) if anyone in future has my problem. Back to the victory dance =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make things much simpler:

```
int count = 0;
int button = 5;
int buttonStatus;
unsigned long timer = 0;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(button, INPUT_PULLUP);
}

void loop() {
  buttonStatus = digitalRead(button); // read the button status
  if (buttonStatus == LOW) {
    if (millis() - timer > 200) { //de-bouncing the button
      count++; // increase +1 each time button is pressed
      // clear screen function should be here
      timer = millis();
    }
  }
  if (count > 3){ // if count is bigger than 3 start over.
    count = 0;
    // clear screen function should be here
  }
  switch (count){
    case 1: // if count == 1
    // show charecter :)
    break; // break out of this case!
    case 2:
    // show charecter :(
    break;
    case 3:
    // show charecter :D
    break;
    default: // if none of above cases is valid
    count = 0;
    // clear screen function should be here
  }
  Serial.println(count);
  delay(100);
}
```

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJ8Cii.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

So each time button is pressed `count` value will increase by 1. you can also add another button to decrease this value...

You might also notice when pushing the button it'll count more than once, you'll also need to De-Bounce the button. [tutorial](https://www.arduino.cc/en/tutorial/debounce).

**Edit:** added de-bounce function.

Comment: Hi again newbie. So with this, I say like Case 1: TFTscreen.stroke(0,0,0);
  TFTscreen.text(":)"); with all my colour settings? Do I also put in void set up that I want the background to be black? I just want to make sure this is what you meant by your thing you sent me, or do you mean to still have the button in the middle but the wires on the other side? [link](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/446294089621569536/630427693183402014/20191007_013403.jpg). My TFT is just blank and wont show up anything before so I wan't to clarify before I start. Thanks again

Comment: @Ijustneedtopassprobs Only two wire goes to the button (what's the third wire in that picture?), ground and pin 5 in this case. yes define your libraries at top like you did in your original code and the sittings you want in void setup. also read the comments in the code that i posted.

Comment: I did remove that one after, sorry I figured that out eventually. It's going through all the faces at the moment. I made up to 5 cases. It's pretty much spamming. I haven't touched the button yet. I'm going to edit my code so you can see my new code to see if I'm extra dumb or not =), once again ty for this